# Passing parameter to WebMethod with jQuery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, json, parameters

I have a simple web method and ajax call and continue to recieve an error that saying that it can't convert a string to an IDictionary object???

Here is the ajax call:

```
var params = '{"ID":"' + rowid + '"}';
$.ajax({
  url: 'EDI.asmx/GetPartnerDetails',
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: JSON.stringify(params),
  dataType: "json", //not json . let me try to parse
  success: function(msg, st) { . . . .
```

Here is the webMethod:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetPartnerDetails(ByVal ID As String) As String

    'Dim objParam As IDictionary = CType(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(ID), IDictionary)
    'Dim rowID As String = objParam("ID")

    Dim objController As New HealthComp.BLL.X12Partners.TradingPartnersController
    Dim objInfo As TradingPartnersInfo = objController.FetchByPartnerID(Int32.Parse(ID))

    Return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objInfo)
End Function
```

Here is what I see from FireBug:

Response Headers
Server: Microsoft-IIS/5.1
Date: Thu, 09 Apr 2009 21:43:59 GMT
jsonerror:true
Cache-Control:private
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length:1331

POST: "{\"ID\":\"4\"}"

RESPONSE:

{"Message":"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections
.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]\u0027","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization
.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeInternal(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean
 throwOnError, Object& convertedObject)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToTypeMain
(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer serializer, Boolean throwOnError, Object& convertedObject
)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.ObjectConverter.ConvertObjectToType(Object o, Type type, JavaScriptSerializer
 serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
 serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest
(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler
.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services
.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType"
:"System.InvalidOperationException"}

Anyone have any ideas about this? Thanks!!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Quick item:

your variable params
`var params = '{ID:' + rowid + '}';`
is a string.

So the line:
`data: JSON.stringify(params),` is redundant (or it should be).
Just set `data: params,`

Next up, on your web method, you converting your result to a JSON string and returning that as a string.  If you web method class has ScriptMethod attribute, you don't need to do that.
Just return the data as the native type, and Asp.Net will do the conversion to JSON for you.

You might read the following articles:
http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/21/javascript-arrays-via-jquery-ajax-to-an-aspnet-webmethod/

http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Comment: You are the man. Thank you so much Chris! I added this:  var jsonText = JSON.stringify({ ID: rowid }); after reading your article. I've read a ton of articles that showed passing parameters with quotes. Yours is the first one I've read that explained AND FIXED it. Mucho gracias!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, it is worth checking to make sure that you aren't 'stringifying' the JSON array more than once.

I accidentally called JSON.stringify() on an array that had already been serialized, which threw a similar issue to the one the OP received.

i.e.

```
var arr = JSON.stringify({ id: elementID, name: Name });
....
$.ajax({
...
data: JSON.stringify(arr),
...
});
```

In this instance, changing the *arr* variable initialization to

```
var arr = { id: elementID, name: Name };
```

resolved my issue. :)