# Parameter to Web Service via Jquery Ajax Call

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, revealing-module-pattern

I am using revealing module pattern and knockout to bind a form. When data is entered in that form(registration), it needs to be posted back to MVC4 web method.

Here is the Jquery code

```
    /*
Requires JQuery
Requires Knockout
*/
op.TestCall = function () {

    // Private Area
    var _tmpl = { load: "Loading", form: "RegisterForm"};

    var
    title = ko.observable(null)
    template = ko.observable(_tmpl.load),
    msg = ko.observable(),

    postData = ko.observable(),

    PostRegistration = function () {
        console.log("Ajax Call Start");
        var test = GetPostData();
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: obj.postURL, //Your URL here api/registration
            data: GetPostData(),
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'


        }).done(Success).fail(Failure);
        console.log("Ajax Call End");
    },
    GetPostData = function () {
        var postData = JSON.stringify({
            dummyText1: dummyText1(),
            dummyText2: dummyText2(),

        });
        return postData;

    }


    return {
        // Public Area
        title: title,
        template: template,
        dummyText1: dummyText1,
        dummyText2: dummyText2
    };
}();
```

The controller code is simple as per now

```
 // POST api/registration
    public void Post(string data)
    {

        ///TODO

    }
```

When i am trying to, capture the data (using simple console.log) and validate it in jslint.com, it's a valid Json.

1. I tried hardcoding the data as

   data: "{data: '{\'name\':\'niall\'}'}",
   But still i get as null, in my web method.
2. Added the tag `[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]` to my Post method in controlled, but still no fruitful result
3. Even tried JSON.Stringify `data: JSON.stringify(data)` but still i get null in my web-method.

I am not able to figure out the solution.

Similar issue was found @ this link 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1555940.aspx/1
even [Passing parameter to WebMethod with jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736058/problem-passing-parameter-to-webmethod-with-jquery-ajax)
but didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

MVC and WebApi uses the concept of [Model Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx).

So the easiest solution is that you need to create a Model class which matches the structure of the sent Json data to accept the data on the server:

```
public void Post(MyModel model)
{
   ///TODO
}

public class MyModel
{
   public string DummyText1 { get; set; }

   public string DummyText1 { get; set; }
}
```

Note: The json and C# property names should match.

Comment: I can't do it with that approach, i need to use JSON.stringify and get the desired. I have updated my question a little. Thanks for you answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Only escaped double-quote characters are allowed, not single-quotes, so you just have to replace single quotes with double quotes:

```
data: "{data: '{\"name\":\"niall\"}'}"
```

Or if you want to use the stringify function you can use it this way:

```
data: "{data: '" + JSON.stringify(data) + "'}"
```