# Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027sentQuery\u0027 & Invalid JSON primitive

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web-services

Not sure why I am getting this but I get this error:

```
Invalid web service call, missing value for parameter: \u0027sentQuery\u0027
```

When trying to execute jQuery AJAX to my ASPX web service.

My AJAX is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: "http://localhost:7665/Service1.asmx/theQ",
    data: "{\"sentQuery\":" + "\"SELECT OPRID FROM vwPS_BC_JOB_PERS_DAT\"" + "}",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (a) {
        alert('ERROR: ' + a.responseText);
    }
});
```

And my VB web service code:

```
<WebMethod(CacheDuration:=60)> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=True, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)> _
Public Sub theQ(ByVal sentQuery As String)
    Dim results As Object = fetchSQLQ("query", sentQuery)

    Try
        Dim ser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim strResponse As String = ser.Serialize(results)

        Context.Response.Clear()
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString())
        Context.Response.Write(strResponse)
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Context.Response.Clear()
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", ex.Message.Length.ToString())
        Context.Response.Write(String.Format("[ERROR: {0}]", ex.Message))
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    End Try
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

I am guessing that the following is correct:

```
data: { sentQuery: "SELECT OPRID FROM vwPS_BC_JOB_PERS_DAT" },
```

However, it does produce another error:

```
Invalid JSON primitive: SELECT.
```

*Huh????*

Comment: never create json manually, it is error prone and you have already made errors doing it

Comment: I don't think asp.net will parse a json string in a url automatically, why dont you use a normal ?key=value query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got this after reading [Chris Brandsma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/736071/277480) post.

AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   dataType: 'json',
   url: 'http://localhost:7665/Service1.asmx/theQ',
   data: JSON.stringify({ qString: ["SELECT OPRID FROM vwPS_BC_JOB_PERS_DAT"] }),
   async: true,
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
   },
   error: function (a) {
       alert('ERROR: ' + a.responseText);
   }
});
```

VB.net code:

```
<WebMethod(CacheDuration:=60)> _
<ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet:=False, ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString:=False)> _
Public Sub theQ(qString As List(Of String))
    Dim results As Object = fetchSQLQ("query", qString(0))

    Try
        Dim ser As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim strResponse As String = ser.Serialize(results)

        Context.Response.Clear()
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", strResponse.Length.ToString())
        Context.Response.Write(strResponse)
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Context.Response.Clear()
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Context.Response.AddHeader("content-length", ex.Message.Length.ToString())
        Context.Response.Write(String.Format("[ERROR: {0}]", ex.Message))
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating the json manually is error prone and as a result of being hard to read is also hard to debug.

Let serialization methods such as `JSON.stringify` in javascript do it for you

try

```
data: JSON.stringify({sentQuery:"SELECT OPRID FROM vwPS_BC_JOB_PERS_DAT"}),
```

Comment: While I agree with not making JSON manually, I don't see any error in it.

Comment: @Musa i think you're right and i did misinterpret... hard to read manual json is part of my point also

Comment: I just updated my OP with the correct way to send the JSON but also get a new error message in doing so.

Comment: but now you aren't sending json ...I would simply send as default form encoding and receive as post. I remove the content type then it is no diferent than processing a regular form

Comment: @charlietfl can you show me an example of what you are talking about?

Comment: I don't know .NET at all ... but default ajax sends data as form encoded key/value pairs the same way a `<form>` does with `name` on input and it's value